# Как решить ошибку File "<string>", line 13, in generate_response TypeError: object OpenAIObject can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, aiogram

Я хочу сделать бота с искусственным интеллектом но мне пишет ошибку File "", line 13, in generate_response
TypeError: object OpenAIObject can't be used in 'await' expression вот код:

````
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token="")
openai.api_key = ''

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def generate_response(message: types.Message):
    response = await openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "system", "content": "/start"}, {"role": "user", "content": message.text}],
        max_tokens=100,
        temperature=0.7
    )
    await message.answer(response.choices[0].message.content)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)```
````

Comment: вы бы лучше токен и api_key спрятали

Comment: Там половины нету

Answer (score 0):

Все методы в `openai` синхронные. Не нужно использовать `await`:

```py
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token="")
openai.api_key = ''

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def generate_response(message: types.Message):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "system", "content": "/start"}, {"role": "user", "content": message.text}],
        max_tokens=100,
        temperature=0.7
    )
    await message.answer(response.choices[0].message.content)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

А если все таки хочется асинхронно:

```py
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token="")
openai.api_key = ''

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def generate_response(message: types.Message):
    response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "system", "content": "/start"}, {"role": "user", "content": message.text}],
        max_tokens=100,
        temperature=0.7
    )
    await message.answer(response.choices[0].message.content)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Если боту пишут одновременно пару человек он отвечает всем по очереди. Можно сделать чтоб сразу как задал вопрос он писал ответ даже если пару человек задают в одно время?

Comment: @Гриша можно, я обновил ответ